# How to find $\mathbb P(XY<\frac{1}{2})$ and $\mathbb P(Y< X^2)$ without convolution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and independent random variables. Find $$\mathbb P\left(XY<\frac{1}{2}\right) \text{ and } \mathbb P\left(Y< X^2 \right).$$ Tip: one can do it without the convolution formula.

I did the 2nd with the convolution formula and I see how to do the 1st with it: $$XY = \frac{(X+Y)^2-X^2-Y^2}{2}.$$
And I have seen the general formula for the [density of a product of independent random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables).

But what kind of trick does one use to get a quick result without any sort of convolution?

Comment: We need a couple of areas. Integrate.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance. Concretely, the use of `\left` and `\right` messed up the HTML-Prerender shown while MathJax is rendering the front page. The layout is just as fine without them and doesn't show this behaviour.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: As stated above, geometric approach is more intuitive than algebraic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first probability is the Lebesgue measure of the set:
$$ E_1 = \left\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2 : xy\leq\frac{1}{2}\right\}$$
hence it is given by:
$$\frac{3}{4}+\int_{1/2}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\log 2 = \color{red}{\frac{1+\log 2}{2}}\approx\frac{5}{6}$$
while the second integral is the Lebesgue measure of the set
$$ E_2 = \left\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2 : y\leq x^2\right\}$$
hence it is equal to $\displaystyle\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}$ as it was well-known to Archimedes.